# reformatting a sequential data file into a data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sequential

I have an input file, now converted to a `pandas.dataframe`. The records/rows are in a sequence which contain related data of the form

```
    survey, a, b, c
    section, 1, 2, 3
    observation, a, b, c
    values, 1, 2, 3 
    values, 4, 5, 6
    observation, d, e, f
    values, 7, 8, 9
    section, 4, 5, 6
    ...
```

The survey record only occurs once.
A section may occur multiple times and will contain observation and value records.
Observations will always be followed by values sometimes as multiple records.

I am trying to reformat this into rows where each set of values is on a separate row with its corresponding survey, section, and observation.

```
survey, a,b,c, section, 1,2,3, observation, a,b,c, values, 1,2,3
survey, a,b,c, section, 1,2,3, observation, a,b,c, values, 4,5,6
survey, a,b,c, section, 1,2,3, observation, d, e, f, values, 7, 8, 9
survey, a,b,c, section, 4, 5, 6 and so on....
```

Can this be done with `pandas` or should I iterate through an if, then else structure ?

The methods I've tried so far are the following (these are probably simplistic and heading in the wrong directions):

```
#pd.DataFrame(hmdDataToProcess.unstack())

#hmdDataToProcess.unstack

#hmdDataToProcess.stack

#pd.melt(hmdDataToProcess, id_vars =[0], value_vars = 
['SURVEY','SECTION','OBSERV','OBVAL'])

#df2 = hmdDataToProc0ess.pivot_table(index = [0]).reset_index()

#df2 = df_in.pivot_table(index = 
#['Example1','Example2'],columns='VC', values=
#['Weight','Rank']).reset_index()

#hmdDataToProcess.groupby('SECTION').groups #, 'OBSERV', 'OBVAL'
```

Comment: Why do you want to use pandas for this? What is wrong with Python's built-in data structures like dictionaries and lists?

Comment: Hi, You should be reformatting the data by iterating every line and put each row as key value pair or list then provide it to DataFrme api.  pandas have nothing to do here with non structured data. Pandas is build for reading structured data. When data stored as json, xml, db table, csv with a proper format.

Comment: Is your initial data structured to have names in a column and each value in a separate field? Like, row1: `name, value1, value2, value3`, row2: `survey, a, b, c`

Comment: The reason for using pandas  is that the result is to be merged with other dataframes. The final destination is to be bulk loaded either directly to a SQL database or via a json file.

Comment: The data is structured as Mark mentions and is nested to four levels. So four levels would make a single dataframe row. The column names would be applied to the final structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it without using `Pandas`

```
s = '''survey, a, b, c
     section, 1, 2, 3
     observation, a, b, c
     values, 1, 2, 3 
     values, 4, 5, 6
     observation, d, e, f
     values, 7, 8, 9
     section, 4, 5, 6'''
list_s = s.strip().split('\n')
list_s = [x.strip() for x in list_s]
list_s
# ['survey, a, b, c', 'section, 1, 2, 3', 'observation, a, b, c', 'values, 1, 2, 3', 'values, 4, 5, 6', 'observation, d, e, f', 'values, 7, 8, 9', 'section, 4, 5, 6']
for el in list_s:
   if el.split(',')[0] == 'survey':
     survey = el
   if el.split(',')[0] == 'section':
     section = el
   if el.split(',')[0] == 'observation':
     observation = el
   if el.split(',')[0] == 'values':
     print(f"{survey},{section},{observation},{el}")
#survey, a, b, c,section, 1, 2, 3,observation, a, b, c,values, 1, 2, 3
#survey, a, b, c,section, 1, 2, 3,observation, a, b, c,values, 4, 5, 6
#survey, a, b, c,section, 1, 2, 3,observation, d, e, f,values, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: I have used this solution then converted the result to a pandas dataframe, finally output to a json file for bulk load to a SQL Server database.